# Token visibility in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, frontend

Is a fetch request token in a next.js app visible to a client side user?

I must to prepare an application using GitHub GraphQL API. I though about using fetch request with a bearer token for it, but I have a doubts about security and good practices in my app.

```
     fetch((`https://api.github.com/graphql`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + TOKEN,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                query: `
                {
                    search(query: "is:public", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
                      repositoryCount
                      pageInfo {
                        endCursor
                        startCursor
                      }
                      edges {
                        node {
                          ... on Repository {
                            name
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
            `
            })
        }))
```

Comment: If you're doing this on the frontend, like your tag suggests, then the token could be intercepted

Comment: It depends on where you're making the request from. If made inside `getStaticProps`/`getServerSideProps` or an API route, the request (and token) won't be visible to the client. If done client-side in a `useEffect` then it will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser), you need to create a `.env.local` file at the root of the project directory and add the secrets.

When adding secrets, you need to prefix the secret with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to expose it to the browser. For example:

```
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_TOKEN=amogussus
```

According to the docs:

> The value will be inlined into JavaScript sent to the browser because of the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix.

Then you might add it into your code with `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GITHUB_TOKEN`